# How to Reset Values of a Form AFTER they are submitted.

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, reset

I have form1 and a submit button that goes like:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Insert" onclick="document.form1.reset();"/>
```

I want to reset the values of my form after the values are submitted. The above code resets them and then submits the (empty) values.

I have also tried:
    onclick="document.form1.submit();document.form1.reset();" but it didnt work.

Comment: if you have pure html and no system of caching the form on the back-end or the front-end then the form will be empty when it reloads after it is submitted.

Comment: No, the submit just executes a php script without leaving the page (I don't know how it is called), it shows a popud.

Answer (score 1):

Append the following to your form's tag:

```
onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I found another way, though I dont know how robust it is since it uses a timer:

onclick="setTimeout('document.form1.reset()', 900); return true"

Comment: It is not a good approach. What was the problem about the solution?

Comment: By the way, if your page includes a submit button named as "submit", it will conflict with the submit method.